# Ace Editor: Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I have been looking for a solution to below described issue for a few days but I couldn't find anything helping...

I am using Ace editor on 6 different DIVs on a webpage (so I have 6 editors).
Basically everything works fine, I am able to create them, set them up (language mode, soft tabs, etc.) and manage their content once the user is done.

BUT I keep having the same error message in the console "Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined". I get it 6 times, 1 per Ace editor on the page.

Here is the JS I am using. divIdsArray is an array containing the 6 DIVs Ids.

```
function initAceEditorFields()
{
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (var i = 0 ; i < divIdsArray.length ; i++){
        var l_arr_splitted = divIdsArray[i].split("_");
        var l_str_code = l_arr_splitted[2];//Each div id contains either "js" or "html" which i am retrieving here

        var l_ace_editor = ace.edit(divIdsArray[i]);

        l_ace_editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
        l_ace_editor.getSession().setUseSoftTabs(false);
        l_ace_editor.getSession().setTabSize(4);
        l_ace_editor.$blockScrolling = Infinity;

        if(l_str_code == "js"){
            l_ace_editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
        }else{
            l_ace_editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
        }
    }
 });

}
```

I am loading the files: ace.js, mode-javascript.js and mode-html.js from the ace package.

I have tried with ace editor builds: "src-min" and "src-min-noconflict" from the github repo and I tested with Chrome, Mozilla and MS Edge but I always get the same error message.

It is strange as everything seems to be working fine (or at least as I want it too). I just don't want to leave these messages in the console when I go to production.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Please tell us the entire error message displayed including file name and line number. Also exactly which version of Ace you are running. The callback stack would also be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I am using Ace version 1.2.3 from 2016.01.17.

Comment: I get 3 messages from worker-html.js at line 1 and 3 from worker-javascript.js also at line 1 as these are minified files. It corresponds to the language mode I am setting up (3 in js and 3 in html). But I do not load these files in my html so I do not know how they are called. I am a junior developer and don't know what callback stack means.

Comment: @HBP : could you have a look at the infos I sent? Thank you! Let me know if there is any more info you might need!

Answer (score 1):

Your ace editor must be using web workers somewhere, then some function called inside a web worker is trying to access "window". The code you've shown us has no references to window. Scrutinize your other interactions with ace to see if you ever pass in a function that references "window" or jquery, or any other dependency in the global scope. If not, then the error in the console is outside your control I suspect.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I will continue to scrutinize my code but i have isolated the issue to this one function. I guess i must have forgotten something in the set-up or it is, as you say out of my control.